# Highstocks chart show StartTime and endTime

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am working on a HighStock chart that should also offer the below mentioned features

1. Each node has a startTime and endTime, the difference would usually be in couple of hundred milliseconds
2. When the chart is zoomedIn further down to milliseconds, the node should become a straight line (parallel to time on X-axis) starting from the node's startTime to endTime.

This requirement is very similar to ColumnRange type of chart which HighCharts already offers, but just that the difference is I need 'RowRange' type of chart which HighCharts  does not support at this point of time.

I wanted to get something similar by having two series where one would be pointing to the node's startTime and the second would be to the endTime. But the sample chart which I am working on does not work as expected at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/ReLF5/4/

```
var OrderStartMS = [
    [1383264040000,0.703],
    [1383350420000,0.7031],
    [1383436840000,0.7032],
    [1383523220000,0.7033],
    [1383609640000,0.7034],
    [1383696020000,0.7035]
];

var OrderEndMS = [
    [1383264040500,0.703],
    [1383350420500,0.7031],
    [1383436840500,0.7032],
    [1383523220500,0.7033],
    [1383609640500,0.7034],
    [1383696020500,0.7035]
];
```

Here are the things that are breaking

- It shows huge gap between the two series though the time difference is just 500ms (which is negligible at a day level). This gap should be shown only if the user zoomsIn upto milliseconds granularity
- Shows 'Invalid Date' though every time input is valid
- If I switch from 'OrderEndMS' to 'OrderEndMS_SameAsOrderStart', then both series would be overlapped, which is expected result. But even if I increase the endTime series by 1 millisecond, I see a large gap all of sudden.
- X-axis does not show the milliseconds granularity even If I zoomIn multiple times

Please let me know if anybody had dealt with the above kind of Charts/Issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use tickInterval value or set ordinal parameter as false.
2. invalid date seems to not be displayed in rangeselector
3. Using OrderEndMS_SameAsOrderStart dispales the same chart as in the 
   OrderEndMS case
4. Try to set minRange parameter.